# Loss of data when using pandas to_csv on dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am creating a data frame using pandas in python and then converting the file to csv using dataframe.to_csv('file_path').

However, there is a clear drop in the number of records and some records are left with incomplete information. Any suggestions on why this is happening/what I can do to resolve it will be great!

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't enough information here for us to replicate your problem. This is usually an important step in determining a solution. Can you post some data we can use to verify your problem?

Comment: This can be tricky but can you produce a [MCVE] ?